# property of a homogeneous linear system of equations that has a trivial solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking at a system of linear equations Ax=0 where A is a 2x2 matrix. A={{1,2},{3,4}}.

I want to look at its properties. This homogeneous system has one trivial solution x={0,0}. Can I call this system consistent? A consistent linear system has either one solution or infinitely many solutions by definition. The trivial solution is that one solution then?

MM

Comment: Yes; a homogeneous system (one of the form $Ax = 0$) will always be consistent because it always admits at least the zero solution.

Comment: @Moo A system that has a solution is called consistent, *regardless of uniqueness.*

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It made things very clear. I don't know how to check two comments as being helpful.